# WPF - Image Control Add Background Color

Tags: wpf, image

Basically there are going to be a lot of Images controls within my application, however when de-selected I can't see them which is really frustrating for layout purposes.

Just curious how I could add a temporary background color or border?

Answer (score -1):

When you click on the control definition in XAML, the designer will automatically select your control. You can then click on the designer control and move it around.

Alternatively, you can click on the Objects and Timeline object of your control to get it in focus in the designer.

Those are the two methods I use to get focus to my controls in Design View.